# File ./Doxyfile could not be found

Tags: github, github-actions, doxygen, building-github-actions

[image]

I am trying to make a gthub action wit doxygen using the yaml code below.

```
name: Doxygen Action
on: ["push"]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: "Doxygen Action"
        uses: mattnotmitt/doxygen-action@v1.3.1
        with:
          doxyfile-path: ./Doxyfile
          additional-packages: font-fira-code'

      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3.7.3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./public
```

Although I put the Doxyfile  under the working directory, it cannot be found. --> File ./Doxyfile could not be found!

I am wondering what I am missing in my code.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: I don't know this action plugin but it looks like that either you have no Doxyfile at the indicated place or you are at a place other than you expected (use `pwd` to see where you really are `ls -ls` to see the files present. It is also unclear which version of doxygen you are running, maybe `doxygen -v` might shine a light on it.

Comment: It is not possible to cut and past from an image but please look at my questions in the comment from yesterday and try to answer these questions (from the image it is not clear where doxygen will be run (!!) and where the Doxyfile lies.  Maybe you need the full path for the Doxyfile /home/runner/work/pythonProject2/pythonProject2/Doxyfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Doxygen is easier without the doxygen-action. I recommend you to try this:

1. Install Doxygen with `sudo apt-get install doxygen`
2. Generate Doxy docs with `doxygen Doxyfile`

That's it really. Or simply with Actions step:

```
- name: "Doxygen"
  run: |
    sudo apt-get install -y doxygen
    doxygen Doxyfile
```

Comment: You are here of course dependent on the available doxygen version with apt-get. This version might be already a bit older. An alternative is to download the, recent, source and compile this.